# "name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name" error when making a template class

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, declaration, function-definition

Node.cpp code :

```
#include "Node.h"
using namespace std;

template <typename t> 
Node :: Node(t nodeDate){
data = nodeData;

}
```

Node.h code :

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

using namespace std;

template <typename t>
class Node{
public:
    Node(t nodeData);
    
private:
    Node *nextNode;
    type data;
friend class LinkedList;

    

};
#endif
```

Node :: Node(t nodeDate) in the cpp class is giving a "name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name" and I'm not sure why since I have the include statement

Comment: **Don't** `using namespace std;` in a header file. It's bad enough anywhere, but it's really bad in a header. You also can't split your template code. Put it all in the header file.

Comment: `Node::Node` -> `Node<t>::Node`. Your code also has some typos...

Comment: Regarding [splitting your template into .h and .cpp files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Your error is rather literal.  `Node ::` is not valid, because `Node` is not a class or namespace.  It's a template.  `Node<t>` would be a class.

Comment: In addition to “Don’t `using namespace std;`”, there’s nothing in this code that uses anything from `std`, so the directive doesn’t accomplish anything.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor `Node` is a data member of the class template `Node<t>`. So you need to write

```
template <typename t> 
Node<t> :: Node(t nodeDate){
data = nodeData;

}
```

And you need to initialize the data member `nextNode`.

It would be better to declare the constructor parameter as

```
Node( const t &nodeData);
```

The constructor definition can look the following way

```
template <typename t> 
Node<t> :: Node( const t &nodeDate) : data( nodeData ), nextNode( nullptr )
{
}
```

Also place the constructor definition in the header.

And it is unclear what the name `type` used in this data member declaration

```
type data;
```

means. Do you mean

```
t data;
```

Also it would be better if the class `Node` would be an internal class of the class `LinkedList`.